# JavaFX 2.1 replace tableview data

Tags: database, tableview, javafx-2, fxml

i have a little problem here. I am working on a little application wich should interpretate and show a tableview of a sql interogation. My big problem is i do not know how to create a new tableview instance using fxml for a new interogation and replace the data in the table with the new data! I mean if i select 2 columns it will show 2 column, after that i select 3 column i will have a 3 column tableview. Any ideas?

Simple: I need to replace the existing interogated data with new interogation data in tableview!

I am using fxml!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: These links might help you (below). 

http://fxexperience.com/2011/10/introduction-to-datafx/
http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/database-design-a-point-in-time-architecture/
http://www.scribd.com/doc/26453223/Semantic-Web-Programming
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/get_started/jsbpub-get_started.htm

Comment: Add an optimal sscce code or code piece that you have done or have tried so far.

Comment: @UlukBiy the problem is that i don't know how to change the date. I know how to import all the table. It's easy. But i do not know how to change the date by the custom sql interogation i gave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found myself the answer. Before executing every sql command i must clear the tableview data, including columns!